# Parsing error in React class Component while using condition

Tags: reactjs, xml-parsing

I get this `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?` error while everything in my Component is set up correctly. I have double-cheked everything and there seems to be nothing wrong. **Collapse** component is highlighted in error message. What have i done wrong or what could cause error here?

Code part with error:

```
return (
                    <div>
                    {
                     isAuthenticatedAndIsCoach ?
                        <h2>Lisa</h2>
                        <Collapse defaultActiveKey={['0']} onChange={callback} style={{ marginBottom: '10px', borderRadius: '10px'}}>
                            <Panel header="Valige treeningu asukoht kaardilt" key="1">
                                <Map />
                            </Panel>
                        </Collapse>
                        <CustomForm
                            requestType="post"
                            trainingID={null}
                            btnText="Loo treening"/>
                      : <span>Teil puudub vastav luba postitamiseks</span>
                      }
                    </div>
                )
```

Comment: It's just as the error says. `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>` That's what you need.

Comment: Just simply wrap with [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) the first part from your ternary. Something like `<><h2>List</h2> {/* other components till CustomForm */}</>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap JSX returned by ternary condition with React.Fragment (or <>) as React expects a single element each time a render function is executed.

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

```
return (
  <div>
    {isAuthenticatedAndIsCoach ? (
      <>
        <h2>Lisa</h2>
        <Collapse
          defaultActiveKey={["0"]}
          onChange={callback}
          style={{ marginBottom: "10px", borderRadius: "10px" }}
        >
          <Panel header="Valige treeningu asukoht kaardilt" key="1">
            <Map />
          </Panel>
        </Collapse>
        <CustomForm
          requestType="post"
          trainingID={null}
          btnText="Loo treening"
        />
      </>
    ) : (
      <span>Teil puudub vastav luba postitamiseks</span>
    )}
  </div>
);
```